# Python simple console game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made this console application that just add 'ing' to the verbs given, but when I try to remove the letter 'e' at the end of the verbs I get this error: " 'str' object does not support item assignment "...THANKS!!!

```
import os

print("---What to do?---"+"\n")

command=""
verbs=[1,2]

while  True:
    command=input("What should I do now? ").lower()
    if command[-1]=="e":
        command[-1]=""
    verbs.append(command)

    if command=="help":
        print("\n"+"Just give me verb!"+"\n")
    elif command=="rest":
        print("\n"+"Fine, bye!")
        break
    elif command=="clear":
        os.system('cls')
        print("---What to do?---"+"\n")
    else:

        if verbs[-1]!=verbs[-2]:
            print("\n"+"Ok I'm "+command+"ing"+"\n")
        else:
            print("\n"+"I'm tired of "+command+"ing"+"\n")
```

Comment: String characters cannot be assigned through indexing - a new string must be created.  For example: `command = command[:-1] + 'e'`

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks but I want to remove the letter 'e' I just edited the code please check it out again buddy, THANKS!

Comment: No worries.  Just slice it off, as: `command[:-1]`. In other words, all characters, except the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the last letter from the string just use `command[:-1]`.

```py
import os

print("---What to do?---"+"\n")

command=""
verbs=[1,2]

while  True:
    command=input("What should I do now? ").lower()
    if command[-1]=="e":
        command = command[:-1]
        # there is one more way
        # command = list(command)
        # command[-1]=""
        # command = ''.join(command)
    verbs.append(command)

    if command=="help":
        print("\n"+"Just give me verb!"+"\n")
    elif command=="rest":
        print("\n"+"Fine, bye!")
        break
    elif command=="clear":
        os.system('cls')
        print("---What to do?---"+"\n")
    else:

        if verbs[-1]!=verbs[-2]:
            print("\n"+"Ok I'm "+command+"ing"+"\n")
        else:
            print("\n"+"I'm tired of "+command+"ing"+"\n")
```